# Inner Join Table (Mapping table)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

this is first time i am try mapping table in mysql  i write this procedure  but not work ? whats wrong ?

```
        DELIMITER $$

       CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spr_GetInformation`(
                    IN cos_ID INT
                    )
      BEGIN
      SELECT 
                     students.ID as 'StudentID',
                     course.ID as 'CourseID', 
                     students.name,
                     course.course_name, 
                     course.cost_fee, 
                     students_Course.net_cost
            FROM      
                     students INNER JOIN  students_course on students.ID     = students_course.students_ID
                     inner join course on course_ID = students_course.course_ID
            where 
                     course.ID = cos_ID;

END
```

Comment: What do you mean doesnt work?It compiles on my machine.Do you know how to call a procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Solve it

```
    DELIMITER $$

   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spr_GetInformation`(IN cos_ID INT)
   BEGIN
   SELECT 
                 students.ID as 'StudentID',
                 course.course_ID as 'CourseID', 
                 students.name,
                 course.course_name, 
                 course.course_cost, 
                 students_Course.cost_net
        FROM      
                 students INNER JOIN  students_course on students.ID= students_course.ID
                 inner join course on course.course_ID = students_course.ID
        where 
                 course.course_ID = cos_ID;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
                 students.ID as 'StudentID',
                 course.ID as 'CourseID', 
                 students.name,
                 course.course_name, 
                 course.cost_fee, 
                 students_Course.net_cost
        FROM      
                 students_course INNER JOIN  students on students.ID     = students_course.students_ID
                 inner join course on course_ID = students_course.course_ID
        where 
                 course.ID = cos_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to terminate the creation of the Stored Procedure with `END $$` and change the delimiter to `;`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spr_GetInformation`(IN cos_ID INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
                     students.ID as 'StudentID',
                     course.ID as 'CourseID', 
                     students.name,
                     course.course_name, 
                     course.cost_fee, 
                     students_Course.net_cost
            FROM      
                     students INNER JOIN  students_course on students.ID     = students_course.students_ID
                     inner join course on course_ID = students_course.course_ID
            where 
                     course.ID = cos_ID;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.emp_code,employee_name.full_name, a.date_of_joining,a.date_of_posting,
a.personal_contact,facility_master.description,departments_master.description,
designation_master.description,emp_type_master.description,category_master.description,
gender_master.description,district_master.description
from hshrc_data.mas_employees a
inner join facility_master  on a.facility_name=facility_master.id
inner join departments_master  on a.department_code=departments_master.id
inner join designation_master  on a.designation_code=designation_master.id
inner join emp_type_master  on a.emp_type=emp_type_master.id
inner join category_master  on a.emp_category_code=category_master.id
inner join gender_master  on a.gender_code=gender_master.id
inner join district_master  on a.post_district=district_master.id
inner join employee_name on a.emp_code=employee_name.emp_code;
```

Comment: Could you please format your post properly, and add an explanation about what your query does?